# Unique co-occurrence pairs with itertools.product()

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of words, for example:

```
[man, walk, ball]
```

and I wish to produce their co-occurrences; i.e.:

```
[('man', 'walk'), ('man', 'ball'), ('walk', 'ball')]
```

I use the following code:

```
from itertools import product
my_list = [man, walk, ball]
list(product(my_list, my_list))
```

which gives me:

```
[('man', 'man'), ('man', 'walk'), ('man', 'ball'), ('walk', 'man'), ('walk', 'walk'), ('walk', 'ball'), ('ball', 'man'), ('ball', 'walk'), ('ball', 'ball')]
```

I wonder how to omit duplicate pairs?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `product`? Why not use `combinations`?

Comment: `list(combinations(my_list, r=2))`

Comment: Works with `combinations`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(['man', 'walk', 'ball'], 2))
[('man', 'walk'), ('man', 'ball'), ('walk', 'ball')]
```